# How to check if this improper integral converges or diverges ?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

$$ I=\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}+\sin x} $$ I took $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$$ and $$g(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+ \dfrac{\sin x}{x}}$$ then tried to find out limit of f(x)/g(x) as x tends to infinity with this i got the the integral as convergent
but when i went with $$ \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \le 1$$ and got $$ \dfrac{1}{x\left(x+ \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)} \ge \dfrac{1}{x(x+1)} \implies \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x(x+1)} dx =\infty $$
two different results using different method ? please suggest something , thanks

Comment: This integral (clearly) diverges at 0.

Comment: yeah that's pretty evident but how i got limit as 1 when applied comparison test on it ? @Did

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light Can you fill in the steps before "and got that the integral converges"? My guess is that you forgot that $|m\int_0^\infty dx/x$ diverges.

Comment: "how i got limit as 1 when applied comparison test on it " Before I can answer this, you will have to be much clearer...

Comment: yeah i got that by doing $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\dfrac{1}{x+(\sin x/x)}}=1 $$ pls correct me if i'm wrong @Did

Comment: and what about my second try , taking $$ \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \le 1 $$ , is it okay ? @StellaBiderman

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light Is your problem stated correctly? The integral at the beginning of the problem isn't the function you analyze. Should it be $\int x/(x+\sin(x))dx$?

Comment: "then tried to find out limit of f(x)/g(x) as x tends to infinity with this i got the the integral as convergent" So, to sum up, you compared f to a function g whose integral diverges at 0 and this led you to conclude that the integral of f converges? Please explain.

Comment: If the responses here were helpful, consider upvoting or accepting them.

Comment: yeah @StellaBiderman i tried but i have less than 15 reputations so MSE showed that it will be recorded but won't be publicly displayed

Comment: I didn't think that applied on your own question, but you should have more than 15 rep now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the second example correctly, and you did the first example almost correctly as well, but messed it up at the end.

> **Theorem (Limit Comparison Test):** Suppose thatthere are two functions,
>   $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=c>0$. Then
>   $\int_a^\infty f(x)dx$ converges if and only if $\int_a^\infty g(x)dx$
>   does.

You correctly computed the limit and found that it is constant. That means that either both functions have convergent integrals or both have divergent integrals. $\int_0^\infty dx/x$ is a divergent integral though, so the correct conclusion to reach with method $1$ is that the integral diverges, not converges.

Comment: oh okay thanks :)  i need to look at the theorem again

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light You also might have analyzed the wrong function. Your function $g(x)$ isn't the function in the stated integral. Your analysis is correct for $g(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in $\;(0,1]\;$ the integrand is a positive function , and

$$\frac{\frac1{x^2+\sin x}}{\frac1x}=\frac x{x^2+\sin x}\xrightarrow[x\to0^+]{}1$$

so by the [Limit comparison Theorem](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf) , the integral $\;\int\limits_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+\sin x}\;$ diverges

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is about the two proofs provided in the OP and the fact that they seem to differ.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I don't agree with you at all: the OP's question is about the convergence/divergence of the integral (read the title). The mistakes he made seem to be secondary.

Comment: Fair. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$